# Android SearchView get ImeOptionClick or submitButton click

Tags: android

I have a `SearchView`. This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("SEARCH");
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

**Question 1 :**

> I am very curios about how can i use the `ImeOptions` that i have set
>   because i cannot find `setOnEditorActionListener` like `EditText`. Is
>   there a way of doing it same as we do in `EditText` ?

**Question 2 :**

> If question 1 is not possible then i found some property called
>   `searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);` can i get this button's
>   click ? Some thing like `setOnSubmitListner` ?? If not then in which sense or how the **Submit** can be used ??

Any suggestion Appreciable.

---

The **motive** is after typing the whole word the user will go on clicking **submit button** or **imeNext** for going to the **Next word** with **KeyBoard not Closed**..!!

Comment: why dont you use `setOnQueryTextListener`?

Comment: @jankigadhiya i was post code for setOnQueryTextListner chek and you can get example of it if you search

Comment: @jankigadhiya if you still getting problem let me know

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
  @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    Log.i("TAG", "==>" + searchView.getQuery());
    searchView.setMaxWidth(570);
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //searchView.setQuery("",false);
            searchView.clearFocus();
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            searchText(query);//method for search text in that you can write your logic

            return true;

        }


    });   }

public void searchText(String text){//Write your logic here}
```

Comment: i want it with a submit button

Comment: see this links method hope you get idea. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: i was tried before which u think to get imeoption button click but didnt find solutiion proper so i was used like this

Comment: i dont want text change i want submit button click

Comment: then there is method onQueryTextSubmit in that you get searchview text on search click may be. i have never tried for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117162/discussion-between-vishal-halani-and-janki-gadhiya).

Comment: miss put log inside Querysubmit and then click on imeoption search button u will get value

Comment: see this link there is explanation https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java

Comment: see mate what i m saying it you are not setting submit button enabled. This is not exactly i want..!! I found the solution by myself but thnxx..!!

Comment: can you post solution please